# Speed up: SELECT statement on DOUBLE

Tags: mysql, performance, select, optimization, double

I have a huge MySQL database table (InnoDB) with ~45,000,000 entries. It contains similarity data containing three columns X, Y and SCORE. (Meaning: X compared with Y has a similarity score of 0.562.)

Now I want to select on X and a SCORE > 0.8.

```
SELECT * FROM tableFOO WHERE X = x AND SCORE > 0.8;
```

But this method takes to long (~20 seconds).

Is there a way to select much more efficiently on DOUBLE values?

Comment: Do you have an index on SCORE and X?

Comment: I have a index on X. But not on SCORE. But I will change ant try again.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index on X and SCORES:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_x ON tableFOO(X);
CREATE INDEX idx_score ON tableFOO(SCORE);
```

(Thanks to the comment by Jon Skeet)

Answer (score 1):

Separate INDEXes won't suffice; you need a "compound" index:
`INDEX(X, Score)`.  (I assume in `WHERE X = x`, the `x` is some constant.)

Check the `Key_len` in EXPLAIN to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check that out. But separate indexes also worked so far.

Comment: A compound index, when appropriate, can speed up a query _significantly_.